# Laravel: Create competition table on the Fly

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, laravel

I'm building a football/Soccer competition in Laravel for our local club and I was wondering if it's possible to generate a competition rankings table on the fly. I have a matches Table with the following data:

```
| id | home_team | home_score | away_team | away_score |
```

So for one competition that has 12 teams, there are n × (n – 1) = 132 rows in the matches table.

Now I would like a competition rankings table from the matches table like this:

```
Position - Points - Team - Wins - Draws - Lost - Goals For - Goals Against - Difference
1.         59       A      19     2       1      63          12              + 51
2.         52       B      16     4       2      58          22              + 36       
...
11.        8        I      2      2       18     16          48              - 32
12.        6        J      1      3       0      8           75              - 67
```

Does anyone know how to do this dynamically in Laravel (Or SQL/PHP)?

And then I have another problem... The administrator of the club also wants to be able to give penalties to teams (for not showing up... etc). Is it possible to that without having the competition table represented in the Database? Do I need to make a penalty_points table which then can be taken into account when creating the rankings on the Fly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get this ranking table with some CASE statements and yes, you should have a table for the penalties.

Comment: Why not a view instead of temp table?

Comment: What do you mean Jarek?